# How to split the wordpress footer's custom menu widget in 2 column

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, widget

I would like to have the Footer Custom Menu Widget to split the items in 2 or 3 column so it doesn't take so much space, but i don't know how to break it after lets say 8 items ( li )

http://marloo.info/sample/marloo/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to break it into 2 columns, you could use the CSS selector nth-child with odd and even...then use CSS to float them left/right.

If you want to break them after X items, you will need to write (or find) a different menu widget that can do this for you.